# how to render pdf horizontally using webview

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

i am developing an application to render pdf on a web view which displays pages in vertical direction. There are many pdf apps which displays the pages in horizontal direction(on swipe),

**how can i render pages horizontally using UIWebView**

Also,is there any other way(other than webview) to render the pdf.

TNQ

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 480 )];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

OR

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIWebView *tempWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];  
    tempWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  
    tempWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    tempWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    tempWebView.delegate = self;    
    [self.view addSubview:tempWebView]; 
    [self setWebView:tempWebView];
    [tempWebView release];  

    NSString *fileName = [pdfFile objectForKey:FILENAME_KEY];
    NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the PDFs are actually created horizontally? Why not just rotate the webview?

```
webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((90*3.14159265) / 180);
```

or

```
webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((3.14159265) / 180);
```